# java - Get the last date of input day of week

Tags: java

I am searching for a method to find the last date of a input day of week from now on? For example: If today is Monday, the 5th march 2018 the results should look like this:

```
Input      Output
Monday     05.03.2018
Tuesday    27.02.2018
Wednesday  28.02.2018
Thursday   01.03.2018
Friday     02.03.2018
Saturday   03.03.2018
Sunday     04.03.2018
```

I hope you get the idee. I couldn't really find a post with something similar, so any help would be much appreciated

As posted in comments, this is the code I have atm:

```
private String getLastDateOfDayOfWeek(String day, String returnDateFormat) throws ParseException {
        int dayOfWeek = parseDayOfWeek(day, Locale.ENGLISH);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Today, now
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != dayOfWeek) {
            // ...
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat(returnDateFormat).format(cal.getTime());
}

private static int parseDayOfWeek(String day, Locale locale)
            throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", locale);
        Date date = dayFormat.parse(day);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return dayOfWeek;
}
```

Atm I have two functions: one that can convert a string to a Calender dayOfWeek number and another one, which is the method i am searching for. Currently it only handles todays day of week correct, the part that should do the work for every other day of the week is missing(comment with ...)

Comment: So input is Monday (2018-05-03) and output is again 2018-05-03?

Comment: @CrazySabbath yes

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: @LAP0109 I must have misunderstood you, do you expect the input to be the same as the ouput? That does not make much sense

Comment: @CrazySabbath The input is just the **name** of a day, like *Wednesday*. And the program is supposed to return the **date** of the last Wednesday starting from *today*. So it is able to answer the question "*When was the last Wednesday?*".

Comment: @CrazySabbath only if the input day of week is the same as today, it should return todays date

Comment: @LAP0109 Please explain what your code currently does and why this is not what you want. Then your question will be in a suitable format as defined in the [help].

Comment: Note that the `Date` class and similar are legacy now. You should use the new classes like `LocalDate` and the others inside the same package.

Comment: @LAP0109 I suggest you edit your Question to include the pithy summary written by Zabuza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().with(                                // Get today’s date, then move to another date.
    TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(                // An implementation of `TemporalAdjuster` interface, used for algorithms to move to another date. 
        DayOfWeek.valueOf( “Monday”.toUpperCase() )  // Get the enum Object with te corresponding hard-coded name in English such as `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`. 
    )
)
```

## `DayOfWeek`

The `DayOfWeek` enum holds seven objects, one for each day of the week.

### English

The names of these seven objects are in English, all uppercase. So you  can get the Object from the English word.

```
String input = “Monday”.toUpperCase() ;
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.valueOf( input ) ;
```

### Other languages

For languages other than English, define a `List` populated with the name of each day-of-week. Use the name generated from `DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`, a method that automatically localizes. Start the list with Monday, per the ISO 8601 standard. Search that list to find a match with your input. Get the ordinal number of your match, 1-7 (not the index number 0-6). Pass that number to `DayOfWeek.valueOf` to get a `DayOfWeek` object. In some languages you’ll need a pair of such lists to be searched, as an alternate spelling may be invoked for a “standalone” use of the day-of-week without the context of a date.

Here is an example of such a class. Beware: I just whipped up this class without much thought and without any serious testing. Use at your own risk. Usage: `DayOfWeekDelocalizer.of( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).parse( "lundi" )` → `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

// For a given name of day-of-week in some language, determine the matching `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum object.
// This class is the opposite of `DayOfWeek.getDisplayName` which generates a localized string for a given `DayOfWeek` object.
// Usage… DayOfWeekDelocalizer.of( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).parse( "lundi" ) → DayOfWeek.MONDAY
// Assumes `FormatStyle.FULL`, for day-of-week names without abbreviation.
// USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. Rough draft, quickly written. No serious testing.
public class DayOfWeekDelocalizer
{
    @NotNull
    private Locale locale;

    @NotNull
    private List < String > dayOfWeekNames, dayOfWeekNamesStandalone; // Some languages use an alternate spelling for a “standalone” day-of-week used without the context of a date.

    // Constructor. Private, for static factory method.
    private DayOfWeekDelocalizer ( @NotNull Locale locale )
    {
        this.locale = locale;

        // Populate the pair of arrays, each having the translated day-of-week names.
        int daysInWeek = 7; // Seven days in the week.
        this.dayOfWeekNames = new ArrayList <>( daysInWeek );
        this.dayOfWeekNamesStandalone = new ArrayList <>( daysInWeek );

        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= daysInWeek ; i++ )
        {
            this.dayOfWeekNames.add( DayOfWeek.of( i ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , this.locale ) );
            this.dayOfWeekNamesStandalone.add( DayOfWeek.of( i ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , this.locale ) );
        }
//        System.out.println( this.dayOfWeekNames );
//        System.out.println( this.dayOfWeekNamesStandalone );
    }

    // Constructor. Private, for static factory method.
    // Personally, I think it unwise to default implicitly to a `Locale`. But I included this in case you disagree with me, and to follow the lead of the *java.time* classes. --Basil Bourque
    private DayOfWeekDelocalizer ( )
    {
        this( Locale.getDefault() );
    }

    // static factory method, instead of  constructors.
    // See article by Dr. Joshua Bloch. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151
    // The `Locale` argument determines the human language and cultural norms used in de-localizing input strings.
    synchronized static public DayOfWeekDelocalizer of ( @NotNull Locale localeArg )
    {
        DayOfWeekDelocalizer x = new DayOfWeekDelocalizer( localeArg ); // This class could be optimized by caching this object.
        return x;
    }

    // Attempt to translate the name of a day-of-week to look-up a matching `DayOfWeek` enum object. 
    // Returns NULL if the passed String value is not found to be a valid name of day-of-week for the human language and cultural norms of the `Locale` specified when constructing this parent object, `DayOfWeekDelocalizer`.
    @Nullable
    public DayOfWeek parse ( @NotNull String input )
    {
        int index = this.dayOfWeekNames.indexOf( input );
        if ( - 1 == index )
        { // If no hit in the contextual names, try the standalone names.
            index = this.dayOfWeekNamesStandalone.indexOf( input );
        }
        int ordinal = ( index + 1 );
        DayOfWeek dow = ( ordinal > 0 ) ? DayOfWeek.of( ordinal ) : null;  // If we have a hit, determine the DayOfWeek. Else return null.
        return dow;
    }

    // `Object` overrides.

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;

        DayOfWeekDelocalizer that = ( DayOfWeekDelocalizer ) o;

        return locale.equals( that.locale );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return locale.hashCode();
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Quick testing.
        // DayOfWeekDelocalizer x = DayOfWeekDelocalizer.of( Locale.JAPAN );
        if ( DayOfWeekDelocalizer.of( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).parse( "lundi" ).equals( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "GOOD - Canada French 'lundi' is parsing to DayOfWeek.MONDAY." );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println( "BAD - Canada French 'lundi' is NOT parsing to DayOfWeek.MONDAY." );
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: Using a String to represent a `DayOfWeek` is clumsy. Your code should instead be passing around a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

## `LocalDate`

Next we need the current date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Better to explicitly state your desired/expected time zone than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

Move to another date by applying a `TemporalAdjuster`. The `TemporalAdjusters` class offers the implementation we need.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( dow ) ;
LocalDate ld = today.with( ta ) ;
```

Note that *java.time* uses Immutable Objects. So rather than modify an object, methods produce a new distinct object with altered values based on the original.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Well, that's what I call an answer and a half, thank you very much, it does exectly what i want